# How to send the post request in wso2 api manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to send the post request in wso2 api manager? What would be the content type, parameters etc.

I am publishing Rest APIs in WSO2 API Manager , I would like to intercept my own API input field validations for each API like input parameter format and value etc. If validation success then API Manager should allow the request to invoke back-end , else reject the request with error message.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, Do you want to send POST request to an API in the WSO2 API Manager?

Comment: Yes i want to send the POST request with JSON as POST data and it should also accept attachments. I checked the documentation but unable to create the POST

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom handler or custom sequence and deploy it for that api. You can implement the validation logic inside that.

see following product documentation

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Writing+Custom+Handlers

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+Mediation+Extensions